# How can I find my Minecraft level?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I have figured out that (on a MacBook) I have to use the FN and F3 keys to get the F3 feature, and that that is how to find your level. However, I cannot find my level and I have been searching a while. Anyone using a Macbook pro that can help me?[image: Please help me find it here!]

Comment: Do you mean the seed for your level? Have you tried "/seed"?

Comment: Level of Experience ? Depth ? Tool stamina ? I don't want to try guessing this detail.

Answer (score 1):

You can find your level here:
[image]

This number is your Y coordinate, which shows you how far you are from the bottom layer of bedrock (level 1).

Comment: Why have I been downvoted?

Comment: I downvoted because you guessed that "level" here means "Y coordinate". You may have guessed correctly, or not. The author could be referring to experience level, world seed, or something else.

Comment: @Rainbolt Given that the OP has found out from somewhere that he needs to press F3 to find the thing he is looking for, it is safe to assume that he means world height. Nothing else can be found on the debug screen that relates to "level".

Comment: @imulsion it used to be possible to get the world seed from that screen aswell. Another possibility is the light level, also found on that screen.